# Swing component name suggestion for a specific interface

Tags: java

As a university project, I have to replicate Raptor. A flowchart interpreter. The interface looks like this

[image]

But as I am not a experienced swing developer, I don't have much idea about which swing components to use for which part.

I know:

1. The whole thing is a JFrame.
2. There is MenuBar on the top.
3. ToolBar exactly beneath it.

Question 1: Am I right?

Question 2: What component should I use for left hand side *symbols* and rest of the part named *main* in the picture? What you would have used?

Note 1: We can drag and drop the symbols from Symbols to main.

Note 2: I am not looking for any code. I just want direction. As there are always so many options in Java. It's easy to get confused easily. I researched a lot, but found nothing specific as it is mostly a design issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how complex and *fancy* (if you will) you want your application to be. I would use JPanels to represent the components (start, end, process, etc).

You can use a JPanel with a custom background (in your case, these would be the shapes of your operations. Look up on how to make an image as a background of your JPanel for more information) and no borders. The advantage of using a JPanel would be that you can actually attach events to it more easily.

You can use JTextAreas to write the content of the shapes, you could capture click events on the JPanel and provide access to the JTextArea for editing.

The major problem I foresee is the drawing of lines. The *easiest* (I think) would be to store a list of coordinates of where the lines are (also assuming slanting lines will need to be broken down into two lines). Before drawing a new line, you check to see if you will have any intersections and if you do, you maybe use a different colour for the line so that you do not cause confusion.

Comment: Thank you :) JPanel seems fine. And after some searching I found how to customize it with JTextArea and custom background. JPanel can be made to support drag and drop also. All requirements done.